# Invalid PEM keystore configs error when setting up Kafka encryption

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, apache-kafka, pem

I am trying to set up encryption on a self-managed Kafka cluster running
Kafka 3.0, jdk-11, using certificates signed with an internal root CA in
pem format. I am running into the following error when I try to restart
Kafka.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid PEM
keystore configsCaused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 1196at
javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:98)
~[?:?]at
org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$PemStore.privateKey(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:512)
~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:?]
```

The kafka config file looks as follows. Any pointers on how to resolve the
error would be greatly appreciated.

```
    # TODO: update protocol after first full-deployment of a new Kafka version
    inter.broker.protocol.version=2.8
    listener.security.protocol.map
    =PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093
    advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://
    kafka-beta.internal-hostname.com:9093
    
    security.protocol=SSL
    ssl.keystore.type=PEM
    ssl.truststore.type=PEM
    
    ssl.keystore.key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMsBasd\n-----END PRIVATE
    KEY-----
    ssl.key.password=null
    
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=-----BEGIN
    CERTIFICATE-----\nMkydTbn\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
    
    ssl.truststore.certificates=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMPMd=\n-----END
    CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue when I set PEM files in server.properties it only works if you use a keystore path with a private key encrypted in PKCS8 format and password protected.

ssl.key.password=null doesn't work

Comment: Somehow I also can't get it to work with an encrypted private key. Is there any documentation you could point to which says that the private key needs to be encrypted?

Answer (score -4):

I would recommend to use the config described in
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configbroker

the following is needed on broker side:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

Comment: Nope, since 2.7.0 you can use the _ssl.keystore.key_, _ssl.keystore.certificate.chain_ and ssl.truststore.certificates options to provide keys an certificates as text, simply because keystores must be loaded from the file system and that doesn't work for every broker in a container context (no local filesystem access). Properties as above can always be provided.